# Failed to load resource on some pages with the exact same code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have several ASP.NET WebPages. When I use this ref to my jQuery date picker on some pages it works just fine and then on some pages I get the error. What is causing this?

```
<%--Calendar Code--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/DatePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Could you give us more details about the issue? For example, which error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Is your DataePicker widget set up like this?

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
```

Wrapping it insures that the page is fully loaded before 'datepicker()' is injected into the `<input>` object. This is equivalent to:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```